# How to schedule job in cron.xml in GAE such that job runs every 5 hours after 6:00 am only on Saturday

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to schedule a job in GAE using cron.xml.
My requirement is something like this:
Every 5 hours from 6:00 am on Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

The [Schedule format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cronref#schedule_format) doesn't support such schedule specification.

But you can use a schedule which contains part of your specification and complete the rest inside the scheduled job itself.

For example, you can use a cron schedule like `every 5 hours from 6:00 to 0:00` and inside the scheduled job 1st thing you do is check today's day and exit if it's not Saturday.