# Is there a way to schedule sending an e-mail through Google App Engine Mail API (Python)?

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, cron

I want to be able to schedule an e-mail or more of them to be sent on a specific date, preferably using GAE Mail API if possible (so far I haven't found the solution).

Would using Cron be an acceptable workaround and if so, would I even be able to create a Cron task with Python? The dates are various with no specific pattern so I can't use the same task over and over again.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem? All help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish what you need with Task API. When you create a task, you can set an ETA parameter (when to execute). ETA time can be up to 30 days into the future.

If 30 days is not enough, you can store a "send_email" entity in the Datastore, and set one of the properties to the date/time when this email should be sent. Then you create a cron job that runs once a month (week). This cron job will retrieve all "send_email" entities that need to be send the next month (week), and create tasks for them, setting ETA to the exact date/time when they should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sending emails from cron jobs is fairly common, exactly for the scheduling reason.

Unfortunately controlling cron jobs programatically is not (yet) possible. You may want to star [Issue 3638: Cron jobs to be scheduled programatically](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3638)

Meanwhile you could check this answer for a couple of alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37079488/4495081